# Rename file within MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, file-rename

I'm trying to backup some of my data stored in a big table with

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
```

statement.
The output file is on a network hard drive, so if the network connection breaks just during the dump (it takes one minute more or less) I find a partial file on my network hard drive and I'd like to mark such file as "wrong".
Is there a SQL command that I can give inside my MySQL Stored Procedure that let me rename such file?

Thank you very much

Best

cghersi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename file in mysql, but you could use two files for dump and rotate it only when operation was successful.

Example:

You make dump to 'a.csv', if operation was successful will use 'b.csv' for next dump, otherwise use 'a.csv' again. And so on...

Comment: At the end the way I chose has been to create a simple Java program that manages the business logic on top of the SELECT INTO statement...